# Changing View Background Color with Soft Animation Infinitely Android

Tags: android, animation

I want to create a color changing background animation that run continuously in my view, and I've been able to create the color changing animation with this code.

```
int prevColor = getRandomColor();
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), prevColor, getRandomColor(prevColor));
colorAnimation.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
colorAnimation.setDuration(transitionTime); // milliseconds
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        backgroundBase.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});
colorAnimation.start();
```

It run smoothly, but...

1. When the animation end, it abruptly goes back changing color to the first one without the soft animation like the first time
2. Then, what I would like to do is when the animation finishes, I want the animation to get new Random Color from my Color List so that the color constantly changing from time to time (not just reversing back and forth)
3. I cannot find `setAnimationListener` in the `colorAnimation`, so I cannot use the override method `onAnimationEnd`

What should I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally manage to do it thanks to `Adrian Coman`

I don't use `ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), prevColor, getRandomColor(prevColor));` to initalize my `colorAnimation`, instead I use the default constructor. and use `setIntValues` to change the background value in `onAnimationRepeat`

```
int defaultBackground = getRandomColor();
final ValueAnimator colorAnimation = new ValueAnimator();
colorAnimation.setIntValues(defaultBackground, getRandomColor(defaultBackground));
colorAnimation.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
colorAnimation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
       int backgroundColor = ((ColorDrawable) backgroundBase.getBackground()).getColor();
       int nextColor = getRandomColor(backgroundColor);
       colorAnimation.setIntValues(backgroundColor, nextColor);
       colorAnimation.start();
    }
});
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        backgroundBase.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});
colorAnimation.setDuration(transitionTime); // milliseconds
colorAnimation.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
colorAnimation.start();
```

It keep changing the background color value everytime 2 secs (my transition time) infinitely. But I still I have no Idea why I need `colorAnimation.start();` in my `onAnimationRepeat`

I've tried to remove it but the background color change with blinking animation instead of soft changing color animation like the first time it animates.

Answer (score 0):

1. set fillAfter to true:

   ```
   colorAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
   ```
2. Save the nextColor to a prevColor variable so that you can start the animation from there. Call the method that contains the ValueAnimator from the onAnimationEnd. Don't think you need setRepeatCount() for that.
3. you can use addListener:

   ```
   colorAnimation.addListener(new Animation.AnimatorListener(){....})
   ```

Comment: there is no setFillAfter method in ValueAnimator.
I finally manage to do it with `addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener(){...onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation(){ ... })})`

Answer (score 0):

This happens the because your are changing the color you the initial animation... If you start your animation with the current color of the view, it may work.

Try this:

```
    ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), backgroundBase.getBackgroundColor, 
getRandomColor(backgroundBase.getBackgroundColor));
    colorAnimation.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE); 
    colorAnimation.setDuration(transitionTime); // milliseconds 
    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
            backgroundBase.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
        } 
    }); 
    colorAnimation.start();
```

Comment: it doesn't really changing anything from the inital code because what I need so it doesn't go back instantly to the initial background is `colorAnimation.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);`